# Resize a frame without moving/scaling the image in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have placed a large PDF in InDesign, as below:

[image]

I want to shrink the frame so that only a section of the content will be visible, but without changing the size of the content in any way, so that I end up with something like this:

[image]

How can I do this? [The InDesign help page says](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/indesign/using/frames-objects.html)

> To move a frame without moving its content, click the frame using the Selection tool, switch to the Direct Selection tool, and then drag the center point.

However, I can't figure out how to scale the frame without scaling or skewing the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just scale by mouse dragging as explained in Scott's answer, but do turn OFF the 'Auto Fit' option, which will re-adjust the image inside the frame if left to ON.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Merely use the **Selection Tool** (black arrow).

Click the frame, then grab a handle and move it to crop the internal contents without altering the size or placement of the content.

[image]

Basically, one doesn't "scale" the frame. One merely changes its dimensions directly. If you want a *specific* size for the frame, you can enter values in the Control Bar across the top of the screen.

(Per Lucian's comment, you **will** want to make certain `Auto-Fit` is **off**. It is off by default. But I think we've all ticked a box and forgotten we ticked it later.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, and the animation. For some reason when I do this the image seems to move a bit with the frame:
Before: https://imgur.com/a/72xBe8a
While resizing: https://imgur.com/a/TzhjC6R
Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Sorry @RuviLecamwasam I have never seen that happen in decades of InDesign use. Perhaps it's a setting or preference somewhere? (I'm guessing)

Comment: Make sure Auto-Fit is OFF.

Comment: Auto-Fit turned out to be the problem! Going to "Object->Fitting->Frame Fitting Options" and turning Auto-Fit off made it behave as in Scott's animation. Thank you both for your help, @Lucian if you write your comment as an answer I will happily mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Object -> fitting -> clear frame fitting options, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Auto Fit in the menu ribbon.